# <Outside any known module>, Vtune Amplifier Error

Tags: java, intel-vtune

Currently I'm using VTune analyzer in linux system to profiling java code.

I generated report by attaching it to the running process.

However, in top-down tree, I usually can see [Outside any known module] which took certain amount of time.

When I click it, I couldn't see any thing.

The strange thing is that sometime it can generate proper top-down report.

When vtune can generate proper report, trace file is usually about 500MB

On the other hands, when it can't generate, trace file is just about 5MB

There are plenty of opinion that it is because of "code on the fly".

So, I tried this steps after turning off the JIT option in jdk.

Ofcourse, I ran it under root.

But it doesn't work well.

My Ubutu version is 14.04.1 LTS

Please help me!!

Any kind of probable ideas may be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you start profiling do you see a message like "Cannot profile the managed part of the target process. There is no Java* Attach API available. Only native part of the target process will be profiled."?
Yes - means you are using a standalone JRE (which not a part of JDK). The JRE package does not include Java Attach API to attach and profile java code. Could you please try JDK.

Thanks,
Denis